# How to restart app if it unexpectedly shutdown

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, background, restart

[Skype update text](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=21659) contains next:

> App auto restarts if unexpectedly shut down

How is possible to perform that via SDK?

Comment: Can you provide us a link where Skype tells that it can auto restart itself?

Comment: @MaximMikheev of course, here: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=21659

Comment: or even look here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8 at section: What's new in Version 4.0

Comment: Thats strange :) Now I'm also really interested in how do they do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, some sort of apps can be run in background and can be restarted in specific case. This is from Apple docs

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your application delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your application was launched because of a location event.

My opinion is: Skype is relaunched with remote notifications mechanism.

**Update**

Well, I think I found something. @Malek_Jundi was half-right. Your app should fail with non-zero exit code, but it should be registered as VoIP application.

> Because VoIP applications need to stay running in order to receive incoming calls, the system automatically relaunches the application if it exits with a nonzero exit code. (This could happen in cases where there is memory pressure and your application is terminated as a result.) However, terminating the application also releases all of its sockets, including the one used to maintain the VoIP service connection. Therefore, when the application is launched, it always needs to create its sockets from scratch.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12

Comment: But The user has to click on the notificatino message so it isn't auto restart anymore...

Comment: Presenting alert to user is not the only option, AFAIK. Anyway, just my thoughts on the topic, I don't know how Skype handle this.

Comment: This sounds promising though I haven't found any documentation about the automatic restart. Can anyone confirm a successful restart after the app has been terminated by a crash/non-zero return value?

Comment: Can you detect restart? When app is killed it appears in the background, I would like to trigger some events after that...

Answer (score 3):

Skype does exactly this:

1. Registers it's TCP sockets for VoIP.
2. Logs in.
3. Upon nonzero exit code the app will be relaunched by iOS (Because VoIP applications need to stay running in order to receive incoming calls, the system automatically relaunches the application if it exits with a nonzero exit code.).
4. It then immediately starts a background task (Relaunched apps remain suspended).
5. Next it registers it's login socket for VoIP.
6. It logs back in.

Comment: Can you provide any apple documentation about paragraph 3?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know its not possible to restart your app .. you could kill your app using `exit(1);`  but this is not allowed by Apple and will rejected. maybe you do some workaround by remove some views from the mainViewController and add it again and reset the data and content .. but making a real restart I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whats with the Skype but - Unfortunately, there's no way to restart the app. Even, there is no way to quit/exit the app. (for quitting, please refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27) link section "Don't quit programmatically")

Answer (score 0):

The question is why would you want do that?, if your answer is: you want to make an app to run in an "iPad Kiosk" so in case it crashed you need the app to automatically restart, then, what will work for you is put the iPad in "**Kiosk mode**" and the OS automatically restarts the app in case of crashes.

Take a look at:

http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/447/How-to-Setup-Kiosk-Mode-Lock-Your-iPad-to-Just-One-App

Cheers,