# iPhone app to restart automatically on crash

Tags: iphone, crash, restart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restart app if it unexpectedly shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395142/how-to-restart-app-if-it-unexpectedly-shutdown)

just saw an update from the Skype app that mentioned that their latest version enables the app to automatically start up again in case it crashes.

As much as I would like my app(s) to not crash, in the "likely" event it does, this feature would be real good to have.

Any helpful pointers on how to achieve a similar feature would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, did't realize the significance...Will be more responsive going forward.  My apologies again.

Comment: Tried accepting answers and guess this is a comment and not an answer, I am unable to do that...