# How to auto-restart an app after a crash (like Skype 4.0 did)

Tags: ios

Perhaps you've all heard about what Skype did with their iOS app; it will auto-restart itself when it crashes:
http://bytenow.net/2012/04/30/skype-releases-4-0-update-for-ios-brings-ui-redesign-and-auto-relaunch

I'm wondering how this is done. Does anyone know?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10395142/1228534

Comment: He doesn't have an answer, just a guess

Comment: Then why do you think asking the same question again would make a difference?

Comment: Because he marked with V un-satisfied answer

Comment: Sorry? V? The green checkmark means 'Accepted Answer'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone app to restart automatically on crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408199/iphone-app-to-restart-automatically-on-crash)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Skype does, in my case I made an app to run in an "iPad Kiosk" so in case it crashed I needed the app to automatically restart, so what I did was put my iPad in "**Kiosk mode**" and the OS automatically restarts the app in case of crashes.

Take a look at:

http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/447/How-to-Setup-Kiosk-Mode-Lock-Your-iPad-to-Just-One-App

Cheers,