# Automatic relaunch an iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, background, core-bluetooth

I'm writing an app that connects with a Bluetooth 4.0 device.
Because it is related to the personal security, other than be active in suspend, I'd be nice to implement a sort of 'auto relaunch' mode.

I thought it wasn't permitted, but a couple of apps pretend to do it.
The first one is the new version of [Skype](http://bytenow.net/2012/04/30/skype-releases-4-0-update-for-ios-brings-ui-redesign-and-auto-relaunch/), the other is [Find my car smarter](http://findmycarsmarter.com) as indicated in its [FAQ](http://findmycarsmarter.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions.html).

The former perhaps use some kind of [Voip options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395142/how-to-restart-app-if-it-unexpectedly-shutdown), any clue for the latter?
In the settings panel, the appropriate setting enable a mysterious *Cell Tower Monitoring*, but I haven't found any information about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, VOIP services can allow for this behavior. From the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)

> Rather than keep VoIP apps awake all the time, the system allows them to be suspended and provides facilities for monitoring their sockets for them. When incoming traffic is detected, the system wakes up the VoIP app and returns control of its sockets to it.

Other than this method, I am not aware of another way to automatically launch your app without user intervention.

Comment: My app isn't properly a Voip application: do you think that if we declare it as voip and use the voip services to wake up the app, Apple should accept it during the review?

Comment: It would probably be difficult to get it approved if it isn't actually using VOIP.