# Execute program when iPhone restarts

Tags: ios

I'm looking to write a program that will work along side with the components of the iPhone, however I run into the issue of when someone turns off their iPhone the program doesn't restart.  You need to manually restart it.

How can I make it so when the iPhone turns on it auto executes this program?  What can I include in my code so this happens?

Answer (score 0):

This is no mechanism to automatically launch an application at boot time, except for VoIP apps. See [How to restart app if it unexpectedly shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395142/how-to-restart-app-if-it-unexpectedly-shutdown) (referenced by @qegal), and the links there.

Location apps will be relaunched automatically if and when the user's location becomes available.

Newsstand apps will be launched when an appropriate push notification is received.

Other background modes generally do not automatically (without user intervention) launch an application.

See [App States and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) for details.