# How can i relaunch the app after it crashed

Tags: ios, exception, crash, relaunch

[Handling unhandled exceptions and signals](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html)

I just read this blog, and find it is a good way to handle the crash.

Can we repalce the "continue" button to "relaunch"，and relaunch the App if end user want to relaunch our App， or it is correct to do so?

Is there a way we can programing relaunch our App in this situation？Can I push a localNotification to report the crash and let the user know it?

If anyone can give some sample code to do, I will very thanks.
Sorry, my english is not good, hope you can understand me！

Comment: There is no public way to re-launch your app after it quits.

Comment: Maybe I can push a localNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use a library that leverages [PLCrashReporter](https://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) by Landon Fuller. It is much safer, creates standard crash reports, you get all threads including last exception backtrace, allows you to symbolicate them and get the line numbers of your own code. See this blog post for more details why it is safer: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html

There are multiple frameworks and services build on top of PLCrashReporter, which I mentioned in this answer: [Including custom data into iOS crash dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488894/including-custom-data-into-ios-crash-dumps/8511100#8511100)

In addition you can NOT re-launch the app after it crashed (one exception is, if your app is providing voice over ip functionality). There is no code, especially Objective-C code that you should launch once your app crashed, see the linked blog post above, so you can't invoke a local notification either.

Comment: My app is just a Voip, how can i re-launch it? If I can't re-launch it ,can i do something to notice the user just that time the App has crashed?

Comment: If the app just crashed, then the user notices it already since the app disappeared. You should NOT and can NOT try to do anything once the app crashed since you could cause a deadlock on the device. See the linked article above. Regarding restarting VOIP apps, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395340/474794